# How to install anbox in my os?

Tags: debian, package-management

I am trying to install `anbox` but get error messages about failed dependency resolutions.

I run Debian:

```
uname -a
Linux xxxx 4.9.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.189-3+deb9u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- When trying to install `anbox`:

  ```
  sudo apt install anbox
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
  requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
  distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
  or been moved out of Incoming.
  The following information may help to resolve the situation:

  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   anbox : Depends: libegl1 but it is not going to be installed
  E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
  ```
- If I then try to install `libegl1` manually:

  ```
  sudo apt install  libegl1
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
  requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
  distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
  or been moved out of Incoming.
  The following information may help to resolve the situation:

  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   libegl1 : Depends: libegl-mesa0 but it is not going to be installed
  E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
  ```
- If I then try to install `libegl-mesa0` manually:

  ```
  sudo apt install  libegl1   libegl-mesa0
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
  requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
  distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
  or been moved out of Incoming.
  The following information may help to resolve the situation:

  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   libegl-mesa0 : Depends: libdrm2 (>= 2.4.75) but 2.4.74-1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libgbm1 (= 18.2.8-2~bpo9+1) but 13.0.6-1+b2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libwayland-client0 (>= 1.15.0) but 1.12.0-1+deb9u1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libwayland-server0 (>= 1.15.0) but 1.12.0-1+deb9u1 is to be installed
  E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
  ```

How to install `anbox` in my OS then?

Comment: have you tried using snap? https://snapcraft.io/install/anbox/debian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package [*anbox*](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=anbox) is not available in the stable Debian 9 repository: it's available in Debian 10, or also in the Debian 9 [backports](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) additional repository. As *anbox* is only available in backports, it's automatically selected from there (assuming the repository was added), but not its dependencies (unless they too are only available in backports).

A package in the backports repository is allowed to depend on any other package also in the backports repository, not just on its base repositories (ie Debian 9 aka oldstable): there's a whole backports ecosystem.

The correct command to *install* the *anbox* package is:

```
apt-get -t stretch-backports install anbox
```

Which will pull all the package dependencies. It appears from your messages that this will upgrade mesa or parts of it from 13.0.6 to 18.2.8 in the process.

But specifically for *anbox*, that's not enough. *anbox* (actually not *anbox* itself but systems emulated with *anbox* containers) relies on special Android kernel features (eg: [`ANDROID_BINDER_IPC`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/ANDROID_BINDER_IPC.html)) that were in the past only available on Android patched kernels before being mainlined and are rarely added in stock distribution kernels unless said distribution ships tools requiring it... like *anbox*. So those options are not present in Debian 9's stock kernel version 4.9. You'll also have to install a backported kernel:

```
apt-get -t stretch-backports install linux-image-amd64
```

As firmwares and kernels are often tied, for packages you have with their names including the word `firmware` (eg: *firmware-iwlwifi*) you'll also have to try and upgrade them to the *stretch-backports* version the same way if available.

This can change system and hardware behaviours. For example if you're using a proprietary graphical driver, this kind of upgrade might not be completely smooth. In case of problems, you can still boot with the former 4.9 kernel (and usually firmwares packages still keep the old versions around too).